# How to install windows wireless driver?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers, windows, ndiswrapper

i have installed `ndistgk` package in ubuntu 10.10. now i want to install windows wireless driver so where i can get windows.inf file?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an installation cd? You could also download driver from the manufacture site.

Please provide details of the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to [ndiswrapper](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ndiswrapper/index.php?title=Main_Page) ? You only really need to use this method if your WiFi card is not supported via a linux driver.

If you provide the output of `lspci -k` you should be able to get your question answered.